# How to add search box to FBA User Management page?

Tags: search, user-profile, forms-authentication

I have FBA on SP2010.

I need a search box on http://mysite/_layouts/FBA/Management/UsersDisp.aspx

It's very cumbersome to find one particular user in 1000+ database.

Can someone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use you own masterpage in the MySites for this, which has the search box on it. This could be done using featurestapling and a featurereceiver. Just make a copy of the default myysite.master and deploy it in your own feature, then set it as the site's master using a featurereceiver:

Site scoped feature:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  if (properties == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");
  }
  using(var site= (SPSite) properties.Feature.Parent)
  {
    site.RootWeb.CustomMasterUrl = web.CustomMasterUrl.Replace("mysite.master", "custom.master");
  }
}
```